# Magento 2 Image Importer

Tags: php, image, import, magento2

I am trying to write a script that imports images and associates them with products based on the sku.

Here is the code:

```
public function importImages($path){
    $fullpath = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($path);
    $images = array_diff(scandir($fullpath), array('..', '.'));

    foreach($images as $image){
        $sku = substr($image, 0, strpos($image,'.'));

        try {
            /** @var Product $product */
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

            $roles = ['image', 'thumbnail'];
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path . $image, $roles, false);
            try {
                $product->getResource()->save($product);
            } catch(\Exception $exception){
                var_dump($exception->getMessage());
            }

        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception){

        }
    }
}
```

This successfully imports the images (makes a copy of them in `pub/media/catalog/...`), and associates them with the appropriate product.

There are 2 issues however.

1) The images do not have the `roles` / `mediaAttributes` assigned

2) I am unable to delete the remove the images from the product inside the admin panel. When I delete the image and save the product, I get the error: `The image cannot be removed as it has been assigned to the other image role`

Answer (score 0):

Remove roles and try this:

```
$product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))
                ->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
```